# Retrieve Translated country picklist values

Tags: picklist, translation, address, country-and-state

I wanted a Metadata API to get the Spanish translations of Address Country picklist.
Using Translations type or Address doesnt help me get the values.

Answer (score 2):

Translations are always retrieved in the user language.
You can see their labels and codes with this code snippet:

```
    Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = Account.BillingCountryCode.getDescribe();
    List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();
    System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO, '>>>>> Countries');
    for( Schema.PicklistEntry f : ple) {
        System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO, '>>>>> ' + f.getValue() + ' :: ' + f.getLabel());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use query 
`SELECT id,name, toLabel(yourcountry fieldname) FROM yourobjectname` and get the translated values .

sfdev

Comment: Thats not what I intend to do. Country Values may or may not be in a record of an object. I want to retrieve the metadata.